# `:hover` pseudoclass not applying to `<p>`, while `p:hover` does

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

When I hover over the `<a>`, it correctly changes color. But when I hover over the `<p>`, nothing happens. I do not understand why `<p>` does not change color when hovered.

If I replace the selector with `p:hover`, then the `<p>` responds correctly when hovered (but of course the `<a>` stops). How can I get both the `<p>` and the `<a>` to change color when hovered with just a single rule? And why doesn't this “just work” as expected?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            :hover {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>some text</p>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

<sub>To future would-be editors: This code will not demonstrate the issue in a Stack Snippet because it is caused by quirks mode in browsers, something not reproducible in Stack Snippets</sub>

Comment: FYI, styles are not applied to _tags_. Those are just text in a file. Styles are applied to _elements_, and there's no need to speak in code.

Comment: @isherwood - your edit is hiding the problem. This is a Quirks Mode issue.

Comment: Using the StackOverflow code runner, yes the entire thing changes color on hover. But when I put the HTML in a file and open it in my browser, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Seems like you should mention that in your question. Who's using quirks mode in 2023? And my point stands: that's a terrible selector.

Comment: What is there to mention? I opened the html file containing the above code in two different browsers and got the result I described.

Comment: I mentioned it for you. We prefer [mre]s in questions. Stack Snippets are an easy way to provide those. By not mentioning it, you lead people toward editing the question to include it. Then someone has to roll that edit back. Much simpler to simply mention the issue in the question to preclude that churn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is applying quirks mode because it doesn't have a doctype. The quirks mode spec says:

> [4.1. The :active and :hover quirk](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-active-and-hover-quirk)
>
> In quirks mode, a compound selector selector that matches the following conditions must not match elements that would not also match the :any-link selector. [SELECTORS4]
>
> - selector uses the :active or :hover pseudo-classes.
> - selector does not use a type selector.
> - selector does not use an attribute selector.
> - selector does not use an ID selector.
> - selector does not use a class selector.
> - selector does not use a pseudo-class selector other than :active and :hover.
> - selector does not use a pseudo-element selector.
> - selector is not part of an argument to a functional pseudo-class or pseudo-element.

The `:hover` selector meets those conditions, so it does not match the p element.

Answer (score -3):

I tried your code and saw that the styles are used for all tags and the body changes color.
If you want the tag a and p to change color to a suitable color, you must specify that only these two tags change color at the same time.

```
p:hover,a:hover{
color: red;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: this is simply wrong. `:hover` and `*:hover` are the same

Comment: The answer has been corrected.

Comment: The question says "nothing happens" not that "the body changes color". You're trying to solve a different problem to the one the question is asking about.

Comment: Well, the root of the problem is from changing the color of the body, when the background of the body becomes black, the color of the p tag becomes white with the black background at the same time.